# Why is the null hypothesis of trait evolution Brownian motion?

Tags: evolution, theoretical-biology, phylogenetics, quantitative-genetics

Many models of continuous trait evolution assume that traits evolve according to Brownian motion. What is the biological or physical basis for this choice?

I realize there are models that do not assume Brownian motion, but what I am interested in asking is why the null model is so often chosen to be Brownian motion.

Comment: What else would you choose?

Comment: Please define "Brownian motion".

Comment: Brownian motion models the random motion of particles suspended in a medium. In biology it is often used to model situations where change in some system occurs via a random walk.

Comment: I asked because some people use "Brownian motion" as a synonym for [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process). I conclude you are not one of those people.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for pointing that out. I had believed the Wiener process was one and the same with Brownian motion. Reading the wiki page, it certainly does have the same mathematical properties. What other conception of Brownian motion did you have in mind?

Comment: [Lévy flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy_flight).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the simple answer to this question is that the present comparative methodology was largely established by [Felsenstein 1985, American Naturalist](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2461605). For mathematical convenience, he suggested Brownian motion as a null hypothesis, because "...the variance of the distribution of change of a branch is proportional to the length of time of the branch...", and then "...it is easy to see that the differences between pairs of tips... must be independent." Also: "...after one unit of time, the contrast [between a pair of tips] has expectation 0 and [easily defined] variance..."

He explicitly discusses whether Brownian motion is a reasonable model in the section "What if we lack an acceptable statistical model of character change?"

I would suggest reading that paper in more detail if you are interested in the details of Brownian motion applied to phylogenies.

A recent historical perspective on this influential paper can be found [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31094602/).

For a more extensive bibliography/more details you can see [here](http://www.economicgeography.org/faculty/pbergmann/biostats/Felsenstein%201985.pdf).

Comment: thank you very much for the papers! Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Felsenstein's a giant - I should have guessed he had something to do with it...

Comment: @jmah i feel like my main contribution to this website is as a felsenstein stan

Answer (score 1):

Just came across a [chapter](https://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/papers/quantchar/) by Felsenstein on phylogenetic inference with quantitative characters. In it, he states this biological justification for using Brownian motion:

> A quantitative trait that has genetic variation controlled by a single locus will change as the gene frequencies at the locus undergo genetic drift...  Brownian motion is a reasonable approximation to change of a quantitative character by genetic drift, provided that ... [additive genetic variance] ... remains approximately constant.

Felsenstein also mentions that [Cavalli-Sforza and Edwards (1967)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1706274/) consider that varying selection at a locus can be approximated by Brownian motion.

So I suppose that's another slant on why Brownian motion is used.